# How to count multiple column data in linq

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq

```
SELECT country, city, COUNT(school), COUNT(collage) 
FROM T1
GROUP BY country, city
```

I write this query in Linq

```
var count_captainRegisterd1 = (from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                               group a by new
                               {
                                   oc_name = a.Field<string>("county"),
                                   oc_city = a.Field<string>("city")
                               } into g
                               select new
                               {
                                   g.Key.oc_name,
                                   g.Key.oc_city,
                                   country = g.Count()
                               }
                              ).ToList();
```

but they count `country` column. I want `country` and `city` both count

Comment: can you find link to slove this problam

Comment: that does not solve my problem I know it will be multiple keys is written that query but there count single column

Comment: var count_captainRegisterd1 = (from a in dt1.AsEnumerable() group a by new { oc_name = a.Field<string>("county"), oc_city = a.Field<string>("city") } into g
                                           select new
                                           {
                                               g.Key.oc_name,
                                               g.Key.oc_city,
                                               ad= g.Count()
                                           }   
                ).ToList();

Comment: `var count_captainRegisterd1 = (from a in dt1 group a by new { oc_name = a.county, oc_city = a.city } into g select new { g.Key.oc_name, g.Key.oc_city, schoolCount= g.Count(r => r.school),collageCount= g.Count(r => r.collage) } ).ToList();`

Comment: dt1 is DataTable

Comment: so it give me an error

Comment: You group by country and city, count entries in each group... and claim it counts only country? The distinct country values in each group are unique (as well as all city values) so what is it you want to achieve? Is it possible you mixed up grouping with something else?

Comment: Grouping is done using combination of `county` and `City`, which means every `country` in the select, which is grouping count is for a uniquer combination of `county` and `City`, though since a `City` can only exist in a particular `County` physically therefore `count_captainRegisterd1.Count()` shall be your answer

Answer (score 0):

this is the linq of your query:

```
var count_captainRegisterd1 = 
    (from a in dt1.AsEnumerable()
     group a by new
     {
         oc_name = a.Field<string>("county"),
         oc_city = a.Field<string>("city")
     } into g
     select new
     {
          Country = g.Key.oc_name,
          City = g.Key.oc_city,
          SchoolCount = g.Count(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Field<string>("school"))),
          CollageCount = g.Count(r => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Field<string>("collage")))
      }).ToList();
```

Comment: r.Field<string>("school") 
connot convert lambda experrion

Comment: sorry, I edited the answer and it doesn't count null like SQL query and with `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` it doesn't count empty and spaces too.

Answer (score 0):

Alas you forgot to write your T1 class. It seems to me that besides an Id it also has a `Country` a `City` and a one-to-many relation with `School` and `Collage` (did you mean `College`?). Something like this:

```
class T1
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Country {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}

    // relations: every T1 has zero or more Schools and Colleges:
    public virtual ICollection<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<College> Colleges {get; set;}
}
public class School
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     // every School belongs to exactly one T1 using virtual key
     public int T1Id {get; set;}
     public virtual T1 T1 {get; set;}
     ...
}
 public class College
{
     public int Id {get; set;}
     // every College belongs to exactly one T1 using virtual key
     public int T1Id {get; set;}
     public virtual T1 T1 {get; set;}
     ...
}
class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<T1> T1s {get; set;}
    public DbSet<School> Schools {get; set;}
    public DbSet<College> Colleges {get; set;}
}
```

This is enough for entity framework to understand what kine of relations you wanted to design.

Your query will be:

```
var result = myDbContext.T1s.GroupBy(item => new {item.Country, item.city})
    .Select(group => new
    {
        Country = group.Key.Country,
        City = group.Key.City,
        NumberOfSchools = group.SelectMany(groupElement => groupElement.Schools)
           .Count(),
        NumberOfColleges = group.SelectMany(groupElement => groupElement.Colleges)
            .Count(),
    })
```

In words: from every element in your sequence of T1, make groups of elements with the same city / country combination. There may be several same city / country combinations (there are many places called York in USA). So a group may have several elements. From every element in a group, take the common city / country which is stored in the group's key. From all elements in the group take the Schools and count all Schools together. Do the same with the colleges.

Mind: you get the Schools from York in Arizona and York in South Dakota together. Not sure if that is what you want, but that is what your SQL does.

### Final remark

Every City is in a Country. Every Country has zero or more Cities. Wouldn't it be better to put Cities and Countries in their own tables, with a one to many relation in it? For instance, if you rename "Leningrad" into "Sint Petersburg", would you want to update the table of all 'Persons'? And if "Sebastopol" changes Country from "Ukrain" into "Russian Federation" would youl also want to update all Citizens again? Choose your tables and identifiers such that once you have a thingy it does not become a different thingy if it changes name, or location.